# python IndexError: list index out of range on arp_scan script

Tags: python, linux, indexing, scapy, arp

I'm getting this error when running my code:

```
  prefix = ip.split('.')[0] + '.' + ip.split('.')[1] + '.' + ip.split('.')[2] + '.'
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I didn't write the script myself. I need to perform an arp scan on intranet and get as output every IP-addr that responds. My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging
import subprocess
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage - ./arp_disc.py [interface]")
    print("Example - ./arp_disc.py eth0")
    print("Example will perform an ARP scan of the local subnet to which eth0 is assigned")
    sys.exit()

interface = str(sys.argv[1])

ip = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig " + interface + " | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1", shell=True).strip()
prefix = ip.split('.')[0] + '.' + ip.split('.')[1] + '.' + ip.split('.')[2] + '.'

for addr in range(0,254):
    answer=sr1(ARP(pdst=prefix+str(addr)),timeout=1,verbose=0)
    if answer == None:
        pass
    else:
        print prefix+str(addr)
```

Comment: what is the value of ip when that line gets called?

Comment: Do you split on "." or "%"?

Comment: eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.53.73.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.53.73.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fea6:1fa8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:a6:1f:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10603  bytes 8042950 (7.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6049  bytes 672030 (656.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  base 0x2024

Comment: I'm not at home right now so I'll check later but is it possible that I get out of range error because    `ip = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig " + interface + " | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f` calls    `inet addr` but eth0 gives    `inet` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
ip = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig " + interface + " | grep 'inet' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '' -f 1", shell=True).strip()
ip= ip[5:]
```